# Change product's attribute term names in dopdowns with ACF in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

I have Variable products with Attributes and Term inside them.
I created (with ACF) an additional Custom field for every Product Attribute term 'external_name'.

I am using this code to get custom rules in ACF *(see the screenshot at the end)*:

```
add_filter( 'acf/location/rule_types', function( $choices ){
$choices[ __("Other",'acf') ]['wc_prod_attr'] = 'WC Product Attribute';
return $choices;} );

add_filter( 'acf/location/rule_values/wc_prod_attr', function( $choices ){
foreach ( wc_get_attribute_taxonomies() as $attr ) {
    $pa_name = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $attr->attribute_name );
    $choices[ $pa_name ] = $attr->attribute_label;
}
return $choices;} );

add_filter( 'acf/location/rule_match/wc_prod_attr', function( $match, $rule, $options ){
if ( '==' === $rule['operator'] ) {
    $match = $rule['value'] === $options['ef_taxonomy'];
} elseif ( '!=' === $rule['operator'] ) {
    $match = $rule['value'] !== $options['ef_taxonomy'];
}
return $match;}, 10, 3 );
```

I need to change Term's name in Attribute's dropdown depending on its Custom field (if not empty).

Here is my code from `functions.php`:

```
 function filter_woocommerce_variation_option_name( $term_name ) { 
    $attribute_taxonomies = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();
    if ( $attribute_taxonomies )
    {
        foreach ($attribute_taxonomies as $tax)
        {
            if (taxonomy_exists(wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($tax->attribute_name))){
                $taxonomy = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($tax->attribute_name);
                $terms = get_terms($taxonomy, 
                    array(
                        'orderby'    => 'name',
                        'order'      => 'ASC',
                        "hide_empty" => false
                    )
                );

                /** Loop through every term */
                $external = '';
                foreach($terms as $term){
                    $termId = $term->term_id;
                    if ($external = get_field('external_name', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id)) {
                        ?><pre><?php print_r($term_name) ?></pre><?php
                        $term_name = $external;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $term_name;
};

add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 'filter_woocommerce_variation_option_name', 10, 1 );
```

For now I have 1 changed name taken from Custom field for ALL terms.
Any thoughts?

---

**Additional details:**

I'm using ACF (not PRO).
Woocommerce - Version 3.3.5.
Wordpress - Version 4.9.5

I created a CF group **"Attribute Fields"** with custom field **"External Attribute Name"** inside… *(see the screen shot below)*.

[image: CF]

Comment: Thanks for Your attention to my question. I added details.

Comment: I added rules. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** *(Solve empty attribute values bug and code optimization)*

Here is the correct code to replace product attribute Term Name by the ACF custom field value in the product attribute dropdown in single variable product pages:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 'filter_woocommerce_variation_option_name', 10, 1 );
function filter_woocommerce_variation_option_name( $term_name ) {
    global $product;

    // Loop through Product attributes used for variations in the current variable product
    foreach( $product->get_variation_attributes() as $taxonomy => $term_slugs ){
        foreach( $term_slugs as $slug ){
            $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $slug, $taxonomy );
            if ( $term->name == $term_name ){
                // Finding the matching term to be replaced
                $external_name = get_field('external_name', $taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id );
                if ( isset($external_name) && ! empty($external_name) )
                    return $external_name;
            }
        }
    }
    return $term_name;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's really works, but only for Terms with Custom Field. Other terms are empty in dropdown.

Comment: @VasiliyKrasnopevtsev I will solve that quickly, as I haven't try that mixing terms without ACF…

Comment: You mean to add text field for External name without ACF?